# Highlight menu as div content scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, scroll, highlight

I have a `<ul>` navigation that I want to highlight once my scrollable div gets to the specific part of the page.

One problem on getting it to work is my navigation is sortable so parts can often change, be re-ordered, or even removed.

Each `<li>` in the navigation connects to a specific `form` in my scrollable content which changes order or get's removed when the navigation changes.

The scrollable content is called `#reportContainer` which has a fixed height of 100% of the browser page through javascript.

```
<ul id="reportNav">
  <li class="nav-active"><a id="section1" href="#">Section 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="section2" href="#">Section 2</a></li>
  <li><a id="section3" href="#">Section 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="reportContainer">
  <form action="#" id="section1">...</form>
  <form action="#" id="section2">...</form>
  <form action="#" id="section3">...</form>
</div>
```

I have gotten to the point where I can recognize that the div is scrolling but I can't figure out how to get it to activate when the `form` get's to the top of the div.

I am basing this off of a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/) I found. If anyone could shed some light on this I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
var lastId, topMenu = $("#reportNav"), topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight(),
// All list items
menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
// Anchors corresponding to menu items
scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
  var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
  if (item.length) { return item; }
});


$("#reportContainer").scroll(function(){
// Get container scroll position
var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

// Get id of current scroll item
var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
 if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
   return this;
});
// Get the id of the current element
cur = cur[cur.length-1];
var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

if (lastId !== id) {
   lastId = id;
   // Set/remove active class
   menuItems
     .parent().removeClass("nav-active")
     .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("nav-active");
}                   
});
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: @adamb i can't get that to work

Comment: Not very descriptive... Perhaps open a new question with your issues for implementing the bootstrap solution and link to it in these comments.

Comment: @adamb I mean, the bootstrap solution is one line of code. There isn't really much description to give. I added `data-target` to my reportContainer and I added the javascript. not really trying to implement a bootstrap solution to begin with though, so I think ill try and figure out an alternative. thanks though